# Updating GFortran on Scientific Linux 7?

Tags: yum, upgrade, gcc, scientific-linux

I have a software application that requires updating GFortran to a newer version before making the program.  I updated `gcc`, but GFortran did not update.  This is on Scientific Linux 7.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.0

$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
```

How do I get GFortran to update?  Even if it is just for this application?  I'm using `yum`.

Edit:  Searching for gfortran packages give the following:

`$ sudo yum search all gfortran
Loaded plugins: langpacks
============================== Matched: gfortran ===============================
gcc-gfortran.x86_64 : Fortran support
compat-gcc-44-gfortran.x86_64 : Fortran support for compatibility compiler
compat-libgfortran-41.i686 : Compatibility Fortran 95 runtime library version
                           : 4.1.2
compat-libgfortran-41.x86_64 : Compatibility Fortran 95 runtime library version
                             : 4.1.2
libgfortran.i686 : Fortran runtime
libgfortran.x86_64 : Fortran runtime
libgfortran-static.i686 : Static Fortran libraries
libgfortran-static.x86_64 : Static Fortran libraries
mingw32-gcc-gfortran.x86_64 : MinGW Windows cross-compiler for FORTRAN for the
                            : win32 target
mingw64-gcc-gfortran.x86_64 : MinGW Windows cross-compiler for FORTRAN for the
                            : win64 target`

When I try to install gcc-gfortran.x86_64, I get

`$ yum install gcc-gfortran.x86_64
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Package gcc-gfortran-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

It's stuck on the old version.

Edit 2:  Okay.  In order to get something newer to show up, I tried to install `devtoolset-7`.  It didn't show up in `yum search`, but the way to get the package available in Scientific Linux is this:

`yum install yum-conf-repos
yum install yum-conf-softwarecollections`

Now, `devtoolset-7` shows up in `yum search`, but I get this output when trying to install:

`$ sudo yum install devtoolset-7
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: devtoolset-7-gcc-gfortran-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.x86_64 (softwarecollections)
           Requires: libgfortran4 >= 7.1.1-2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

But,

`$ sudo yum search libgfortran4
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Warning: No matches found for: libgfortran4
No matches found`

Comment: Scientific Linux is based on RHEL (Red Hat), my guess is that it uses its package manager as well, `yum`

Comment: https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/ `# yum install devtoolset-7-gcc-gfortran` : You get version 7.2.1 → http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/devtoolset-7/ Repo files 1. http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-scl-rh-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm 2. http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm → Both "repo packages" are required.

Comment: I am using `yum`.  Unfortunately, I'm getting that the `devtoolset-7-gcc-gfortran` isn't available either.

Comment: Download "repo packages", and install : `yum install ./centos-release-scl-rh-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm` ... `yum install ./centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm`

Comment: @ KnudLarson I downloaded both repo packages and attempted the yum install, but got the error `does not update installed package.  Error: Nothing to do`, for both packages.  I'm very much a novice at SL, but isn't it still a bit different from CentOS?  To get the devtoolset to show, CentOS commands didn't word, but specific SL7 commands did.

Comment: Okay, so `sudo yum install ./libgfortran4-7.1.1-2.2.1.el7.x86_64.rpm` installed the missing package and the `devtoolset-7` finally installed and the GFortran finally updated.  Now to see if the GFortran compiles the application.

Answer (score 1):

If the package manager installed is `yum` (I noticed it in your question's tags), you can use the following to update GNU Fortran to the latest version available:

```
$ yum update gcc-gfortran
```

Comment: Hm, it says that that package is not available.  Is this a Scientific Linux thing?

Comment: Could you try running `yum search gfortran`? It should list available `gfortran` packages.

Comment: I'll put the output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Please edit as necessary.  And thank you Knud Larson for the reference repo packages.

In order for my version of to SL7 to even see a more recent version of GFortran to download, I attempted to install `devtoolset-7`.  In order to access `devtoolset-7`, I needed to use these SL7 commands

`# yum install yum-conf-repos`

`# yum install yum-conf-softwarecollections`

Then devtoolset-7 was available to install.  However, when attempting to install the package, `libgfortran4` was not available.  In order to get everything to install, I downloaded the repo packages suggested by Knud Larson plus libgfortran from CentOS and installed the libgfortran4

`# yum install ./libgfortran4-7.1.1-2.2.1.el7.x86_64.rpm`

Then `devtoolset-7` installed

`# yum install devtoolset-7-gcc-gfortran.x86_64`

And now it's working.  Thanks everyone.